# Fabric.js moving the points of a polygon shape fails when flipped

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, polygon

Wasted weeks - Need solution to edit Polygons using either Fabric.js and Konva.js - Both have no way to actually update the poly points and transformer when the poly or it's points are MOVED, FLIPPED or MIRRORED. I'll assume the array points need to be reversed and the end the starting index switch depending on the quadrant the poly has been flipped.
If anyone have a solution please post. Fabric.js code in CodePen: https://codepen.io/Rstewart/pen/LYbJwQE

```
   /* CODE FROM POLY DEMO ON FABRIC WEBSITE - CODE FAILS WHEN FLIPPED OR MIRRORED */
function polygonPositionHandler(dim, finalMatrix, fabricObject) {
  var x = (fabricObject.points[this.pointIndex].x - fabricObject.pathOffset.x),
      y = (fabricObject.points[this.pointIndex].y - fabricObject.pathOffset.y);
  return fabric.util.transformPoint( { x: x, y: y },
    fabric.util.multiplyTransformMatrices(
      fabricObject.canvas.viewportTransform,
      fabricObject.calcTransformMatrix()
    )
  );
}

function actionHandler(eventData, transform, x, y) {
  var polygon = transform.target,  currentControl = polygon.controls[polygon.__corner],
      mouseLocalPosition = polygon.toLocalPoint(new fabric.Point(x, y), 'center', 'center'),
      polygonBaseSize = polygon._getNonTransformedDimensions(), size = polygon._getTransformedDimensions(0, 0),
      finalPointPosition = {
        x: mouseLocalPosition.x * polygonBaseSize.x / size.x + polygon.pathOffset.x,
        y: mouseLocalPosition.y * polygonBaseSize.y / size.y + polygon.pathOffset.y
      };
  polygon.points[currentControl.pointIndex] = finalPointPosition; return true;
}

function anchorWrapper(anchorIndex, fn) {
  return function(eventData, transform, x, y) {
    var fabricObject = transform.target,
        absolutePoint = fabric.util.transformPoint({
            x: (fabricObject.points[anchorIndex].x - fabricObject.pathOffset.x),
            y: (fabricObject.points[anchorIndex].y - fabricObject.pathOffset.y),
        }, fabricObject.calcTransformMatrix()),
        actionPerformed = fn(eventData, transform, x, y),
        newDim = fabricObject._setPositionDimensions({}),
        polygonBaseSize = fabricObject._getNonTransformedDimensions(),
        newX = (fabricObject.points[anchorIndex].x - fabricObject.pathOffset.x) / polygonBaseSize.x,
        newY = (fabricObject.points[anchorIndex].y - fabricObject.pathOffset.y) / polygonBaseSize.y;
    fabricObject.setPositionByOrigin(absolutePoint, newX + 0.5, newY + 0.5);
    return actionPerformed;
  }
}
```